# strlen pointer vs array

Tags: c, string, macos, pointers, memory-management

I encountered a few problems when using pointers vs static arrays. I got stuck in this bug:

```
void LZWCompress(FILE* file, char minCodeSize, char *pixels, int area)
{

int k = ++minCodeSize, i, len = DEFAULT, jump = 0, dicLen;
lzwDict *dictionary = NULL, *s, *temp;

char *curr, next[2], *buffer;

dicLen = initializeDictionary(&dictionary, minCodeSize);
for(i = 0; i < area; i++)
{
    if(dicLen + 1 >= pow(2, k))
        k = k + 1;

    curr = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * DEFAULT);
    curr[0] = pixels[i];
    curr[1] = '\0';

    printf("strlen %lu  %s\n", strlen(curr)); ### strlen(curr) = 0 ? WH ? ###
    if((i + 1) > area)
    {
        //outputs curr
        break; 
    }


    len = len + 1;
    jump = jump + 1;

    next[0] = pixels[i + jump];
    next[1] = '\0';

    buffer = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * len);
    printf("%lu %lu %lu \n", strlen(buffer), strlen(curr), strlen(next)); ### prints out "0 0 1" ###
```

(...) code continues and i get Abort Trap because of this problem

```
    buffer = strcat(curr, next);
    HASH_FIND_STR(dictionary, buffer, s);

    if(s)
    {
        printf("YOLO\n");
        do{
            jump = jump + 1;

            if(i + jump >= area)
                exit(-1);

            printf("%d \n", len);
            curr = (char*) realloc(curr, sizeof(char) * len); ### Here i get Abort Trap 6 ###
```

(...) code continues

Why do i get the expected results when I use an array (next[2]) and not when I used a pointer (*curr, *buffer).

I am using OSX Yosemite if that's relevant.

Comment: Which are the expected results and the concrete bug?

Comment: This code is horrendous.  What's it supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

According to the strlen [doc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/) :

> The length of a C string is determined by the terminating null-character: **A C string is as long as the number of characters between the beginning of the string and the terminating null character** (without including the terminating null character itself).
>
> **This should not be confused with the size of the array that holds the string.**

If pixels[i] equal 0, strlen(next) will be 0.